# Is there a query to use in Snowflake to retrieve the original SELECT statement behind the creation of a table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ddl, dml

I am trying to find the original code behind the creation of a table in Snowflake.

I am using this query:

```sql
SELECT GET_DDL('table', 'table1');
```

This is only giving me the original DDL behind the table. I would need the full code (as in the original SQL SELECT statement).

Anyone know what query could get me that?

Answer (score 0):

You can query `QUERY_HISTORY` and get the SQL statement (and other data) using the following:

```
// Be sure to use a role with permission to perform the following

SELECT
    *
FROM
    SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
WHERE
    QUERY_TEXT ILIKE '%create%table%table1%'
ORDER BY END_TIME DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I get the error message that "SQL compilation error: Database 'SNOWFLAKE' does not exist or not authorized.". Do I need to replace that part of the code with the name of my own database and warehouse?

Comment: This error means the role you're using does not have permission to query that db. You must use a higher level role – the highest being `ACCOUNTADMIN` @JustineMit

Comment: Makes sense. You dont have another possible query for someone with a lower role?

Comment: Query is not possible without this role. If you wanted to be fancy, you can have someone with a higher role create a table populated by this query, then grant a lower role access to that table. But that's a lot. @JustineMit